# How to embed 3 videos horizontally using media9?

Tags: media9

I am using `media9` package. I want to insert 3 videos horizontally & then in the next row again 2 videos.

```
\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=50pt,height=50pt,
  addresource=camera1-.mp4,
  flashvars={%
     source=camera1-.mp4% same path as in addresource!
   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
   &loop=true%        % variables
  }  
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=50pt,height=50pt,
  addresource=camera2-.mp4,
  flashvars={%
     source=camera2-.mp4% same path as in addresource!
   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
   &loop=true%        % variables
  }  
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=50pt,height=50pt,
  addresource=camera6-.mp4,
  flashvars={%
     source=camera6-.mp4% same path as in addresource!
   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
   &loop=true%        % variables
  }  
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=50pt,height=50pt,
  addresource=camera4-.mp4,
  flashvars={%
     source=camera4-.mp4% same path as in addresource!
   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
   &loop=true%        % variables
  }  
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=50pt,height=50pt,
  addresource=camera7-.mp4,
  flashvars={%
     source=camera7-.mp4% same path as in addresource!
   &autoPlay=true%    % optional configuration
   &loop=true%        % variables
  }  
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
```

Please help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) You can format code by using the {} command in the edit window or by indenting using four spaces

Answer (score 1):

`\includemedia` behaves like `\includegraphics` or like any other TeX box: They are put one after another. If separated by spaces, those boxes that don't fit onto the current text line are moved to the next, and `\\` forces a line break.

Try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{media9}

\begin{document}
\noindent Text before\\
\includemedia[width=50pt,height=50pt]{}{}\includemedia[width=50pt,height=50pt]{}{}\includemedia[width=50pt,height=50pt]{}{}\\
\includemedia[width=50pt,height=50pt]{}{}\includemedia[width=50pt,height=50pt]{}{}\\
Text after.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it does not solve my problem. The code you have given It only align one video & text placed horizontal to that video. I want all the videos placed horizontally one by one. No text should be there. Is it possible or not?

Comment: The text was inserted to demonstrate how TeX places boxes of arbitrary content. If you don't want text, omit it. The remainder is what you requested: Three videos on the first line, followed by two videos on the next.

Comment: I some how managed to split the frame & add 2 videos horizontally.
\noindent{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.20\linewidth}
\hspace{.1pt}
\end{minipage}}
\noindent{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\linewidth}
\includemedia[
activate=pageopen,
width=70pt,height=50pt,
addresource=camera1-.mp4,
flashvars={source=camera1-.mp4 &autoPlay=true &loop=true
}]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{minipage}}
\hfill{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\includemedia[
activate=pageopen,
width=70pt,height=50pt,
addresource=camera6-.mp4,
flashvars={source=camera6-.mp4 &autoPlay=true &loop=true
}]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{minipage}
}

Comment: The code you have written does not work. It is still showing in vertical order.

Comment: Perhaps the `\textwidth` used is too small to keep three videos of the given width (`50pt`) on one line. Which document class are you using? `beamer`? `article`? Provide a minimal compilable example.